# Sound sensor signals with time bracket

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I've tried many codes for this to work but anything isn't helping at all, so my code should work like this: If a sound sensor (3 pins, A2) sends 5 signals into the Arduino within 10 seconds (the time gap of every signal varies, but doesn't matter as long as it sends 5 signals), the LED (13) will light up. This is my recent code if it could help

```
int led=13;
int sensor=A2;

void setup()
{ 
   pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(sensor, INPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    unsigned long StartMillis = millis();
    unsigned long CurrentMillis = millis();
    int signal_count=digitalRead(sensor);
    int signal_limit=5;
    Serial.println(signal_count);

    while ((CurrentMillis - StartMillis)==5000)
    if (digitalRead(sensor)=0)
    {     signal_count ++;
        Serial.println(signal_count);
    }
    if (signal_count>signal_limit) {
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    }
    else {
    digitalWrite(led,LOW);
    }
}
```

Comment: think about the first two program lines inside the loop() block .... what do they do?

Comment: What sound sensor are you using? Is its output analog or digital? And what do you mean by "signal"? What counts as a "signal" for you?

Comment: I'm using digital sound detector sensor module. I don't know but it prolly uses analog (that's what I got from website references). The signal I referred to is the signal sent by the sound sensor to the arduino (HIGH or LOW)

Comment: Still you didn't explain what a "signal" is. Does it mean, that the sensor should go high and then low ( a pulse)? Or how do you want to count "signals"?

Comment: I just wanted to count the HIGH signals, then use the number of signals recieved in a short amount of time to trigger a led to light up

Answer (score 1):

Your handling of `millis()` is wrong. With these two lines:

```
unsigned long StartMillis = millis();
unsigned long CurrentMillis = millis();
```

`StartMillis` will always have the same value as `CurrentMillis`. (Ok, I guess its possible for `millis()` to return a value that's increased by 1 the second time it's called, but that is **extremely** unlikely. The 2 lines takes much less than a millisecond to execute.)

Your

```
while ((CurrentMillis - StartMillis)==5000)
```

will never evaluate to true, so the code in the while block will never execute.

This `if` statement is also wrong:

```
if (digitalRead(sensor)=0)
```

You want `==` (comparison) not `=` assignment. I'm surprised the compiler even allowed that to compile, since you are trying to set the function `digitalRead(sensor)` to 0, which doesn't make sense.

Change that code to read:

```
if (digitalRead(sensor)==0)
```

(Assuming you want the body of the if statement to execute when your sensor value is 0.)